# Displaying the password on a filtered request

Tags: strapi

- **Strapi Version**: 4.4.5
- **Operating System**: linux
- **Database**: sqlite
- **Node Version**: 16.17.0
- **NPM Version**:
- **Yarn Version**: 1.22.19

Hello,

I'm just trying to get all the information from my "Channel" table, namely the product_id and the "users" concerned in the channel. I simply overload my find method like this:

```
module.exports = createCoreController("api::channel.channel", ({ strapi }) => ({
  async find(ctx) {
    const { user } = ctx.state:
  const entity = await strapi.service("api::channel.channel").find({
      filters: {
        users: {
          id: {
            $in: user.id,
          },
        },
      },
      populate: ["users"]
  
    });

    const sanitizedEntity = await this.sanitizeOutput(entity, ctx);
    return this.transformResponse(sanitizedEntity);
  },
}));
```

And for some reason, I get all the user information and especially the hash of the passwords.

So I try to do a select on my populate like this, but it doesn't work :

```
module.exports = createCoreController("api::channel.channel", ({ strapi }) => ({
  async find(ctx) {
    const { user } = ctx.state;

    const entity = await strapi.service("api::channel.channel").find({
      filters: {
        users: {
          id: {
            $in: user.id,
          },
        },
      },
      populate: {
        users: {
          select: ["id"]
        }
      }
  
    });

    const sanitizedEntity = await this.sanitizeOutput(entity, ctx);
    return this.transformResponse(sanitizedEntity);
  },
}));
```

Does anyone have a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is not select, you would use `fields`

[Strapi Population](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/rest/populating-fields.html#field-selection)

```js
const qs = require('qs');
const query = qs.stringify({
  fields: ['title', 'body'],
}, {
  encodeValuesOnly: true, // prettify URL
});
```

So in your case, fields in combination with populate.

```js
populate: {
    users: {
        fields: ["id"]
    }
}
```

Comment: I get a 500 error, my API breaks telling me that the users column (which is many-to-many) doesn't exist, that's why I switched to populate

Comment: No, I mean you need to use fields in combination with select. I will update the answer.